# Python Teradataml Connection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm attempting to use the Python teradataml library for Teradata to create a simple database connection using the logmech of LDAP.  However, i'm greeted with an attribute error of 'NoneType' ojbect has no attribute dialect in relation to sqlalchemy_engine.dialect.

My code to create the connection with the hostname changed

```
import teradataml as tdml
from teradataml import *

hostname = "address of host"
schema = "DL_RBA_DSS"

td_context = create_context(host = hostname, logmech='LDAP', temp_database_name = schema)
print(td_context)
```

When running the code it gives me the following error:

```
File "c:/Python/teradatamlconnection.py", line 7, in <module>
    td_context = create_context(host = hostname, logmech='LDAP', temp_database_name = schema)
  File "C:\Users\UserID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\teradataml\context\context.py", line 287, in create_context
    _load_function_aliases()
  File "C:\Users\UserID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\teradataml\context\context.py", line 532, in _load_function_aliases
    __set_vantage_version()
  File "C:\Users\UserID\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\teradataml\context\context.py", line 562, in __set_vantage_version
    if td_sqlalchemy_engine.dialect.has_table(td_sqlalchemy_engine, "versionInfo", schema="pm"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dialect'
```

I have tried to update the teradatasqlalchemy and sqlalchemy library, but i still am greeted with the error.  It shows all requirements are satisfied:

PS C:\Python\dsssecurity> pip install teradatasqlalchemy --upgrade

```
Requirement already up-to-date: teradatasqlalchemy in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (16.20.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: teradatasql in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradatasqlalchemy) (16.20.0.52)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlalchemy>=1.2.11 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradatasqlalchemy) (1.3.13)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycryptodome in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradatasql->teradatasqlalchemy) (3.9.0)
PS C:\Python\dsssecurity> pip install teradataml --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: teradataml in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (16.20.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: teradatasql in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradataml) (16.20.0.52)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pandas>=0.22 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradataml) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: psutil in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradataml) (5.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: teradatasqlalchemy>=16.20.0.8 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradataml) (16.20.0.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycryptodome in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradatasql->teradataml) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.22->teradataml) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.22->teradataml) (2017.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.22->teradataml) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlalchemy>=1.2.11 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from teradatasqlalchemy>=16.20.0.8->teradataml) (1.3.13)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.5 in c:\users\UserID\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas>=0.22->teradataml) (1.11.0)
```

Comment: How are you supplying the required username and password (and/or logdata) attributes for the connection?

Comment: It's an optional field per the documentation when using the logmech of LDAP.

Comment: It's only "optional" in the sense that username/password can be specified as part of the value for logdata attribute in place of separate username/password attributes..

Comment: What does the syntax look like while using logdata to supply the username and password?  logdata:
        Optional Argument.
        Specifies parameters to the LOGMECH command beyond those needed by the logon mechanism, such as 
        user ID, password and tokens (in case of JWT) to successfully authenticate the user.
        Types: str

Comment: I've tried this with no success as well.  td_context = create_context(host = 'tdhost', username='tduser', password = 'tdpassword', logmech='LDAP')

Comment: Any of `authcid=diruser password=dirpass` or just `diruser password=dirpass` or `diruser@@dirpass` formats are accepted. If there are multiple mappings then you can append qualifiers for database *user=* and/or *profile=* to be used; if there are multiple directory realms you can append a *realm=* qualifier.

Comment: That did it for me Fred!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer Fred, if you answer the question i'll mark it correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `logmech='LDAP'` you must supply a username and password, either via the separate attributes or as part of a `logdata` string.

For logdata the string can start with any of the formats `authcid=diruser password=dirpass` or just `diruser password=dirpass` or `diruser@@dirpass`. If there are multiple directory mappings then you can append qualifiers for database *user=* and/or *profile=* to be used; if there are multiple directory realms you can append a *realm=* qualifier`